# Rails SaaS application Create New Database for Each Client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord

Am creating Rails SaaS application, in that I want to create a new database for each client. How can do this and manage it? Any example there? Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the Apartment gem:
https://github.com/influitive/apartment

If you plan on using PostgreSQL as your DB (recommended), you can instead create a new *schema* for each account, rather than an entire new database.

Ryan Bigg is currently writing a book about this subject as well. He rocks. https://leanpub.com/multi-tenancy-rails